# Only allow the function to be executed after all the previous steps have been validated

Tags: javascript, validation

I am forcing the password change on the first login like this:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("senhanova");
var confirm = document.getElementById("senhaconfir");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

myInput.onkeyup = function() {

  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
   var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  var upperCaseLetters = /[@$!%*?&]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    caracter.classList.remove("invalid");
    caracter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    caracter.classList.remove("valid");
    caracter.classList.add("invalid");
  }


  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  

  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}

function inserir_senha()
{  
    var dadosajax = {
        'senhaatual' : $("#senhaatual").val(),
        'senhanova' : $("#senhanova").val(),
        'senhaconfir' : $("#senhaconfir").val()
        
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'alterarsenha.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data.result){                            
                $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); 
            }else{
                Swal.fire('Alerta!', data.message,'warning');
            }
        }
    });    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="alteracao">
    <form class="alteracao-signin" method="POST">
        <h2 class="alteracao-signin-heading">Tem de alterar a sua senha.</h2>
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaatual" name="senhaatual" placeholder="Senha Atual" required><label for="senhaatual" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhanova" name="senhanova" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$" title="Deve conter pelo menos um número, uma letra maiúscula e minúscula, um caractere especial e pelo menos 8 ou mais caracteres" placeholder="Nova Senha" required><label for="senhanova" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="password" id="senhaconfir" name="senhaconfir" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" required><label for="senhaconfir" class="fa fa-lock input-icon"></label></div>
    
        <button id="valida" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button> 
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>A senha deve conter o seguinte:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> minúscula</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>letra </b> maiúscula</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">O <b>número</b></p>
  <p id="caracter" class="invalid">O <b>Caracter</b> especial</p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimo <b>8 caracteres</b></p>
</div>
```

The inputs are being validated and if the requirements are not met, the user will be notified.
But if you execute the button `<button id="valida" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="inserir_senha();">Alterar</button>` if the new field password and the confirm password field, if they are the same even if you do not meet the requirements, execute the function insert_senha() and change the password in the database.

It should only perform the function when the user fulfills all the requirements

Comment: Ok, so what is your question please?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  
The problem is that in the new password I ask to paste 8 characters and fulfill those requirements, but if the user puts in the new password only 3 characters and in the confirm password also 3 characters equal to the previous field, this way inserts it in the database changing the password and should only leave after meeting all the requirements

Comment: @RiggsFolly I intend to allow you to execute the function only after all the previous steps have been validated in the inputs. If you do change your password, if you still don't meet the requirements, be sure to run the `inserir_senha()` function.  
Can you help?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your question and other details.  Some users will not bother by searching comments to find what you're asking.

Comment: I must add that you should never trust client side validation. You should always check the values in the back-end to be sure, as client side code cannot be trusted. But if you want to check to show errors on the page without calling, in that case you should wrap the `inherit_senha` function with validation function. Also you are checking for validity `onkeyup` event. Maybe you can store the validity state in a variable so you can check it on click like `isAllInputsValid && inherit_senha()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to do this validation was in php.

Before inserting in the database, I check if the variable contains a capital letter, lower case, number, special character and if it has at least 8 characters like this:

```
$ucl = preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $senhanova); // Uppercase Letter
$lcl = preg_match('/[a-z]/', $senhanova); // Lowercase Letter
$Dig = preg_match('/\d/', $senhanova); // Numeral
$nos = preg_match('/[@$!%*?&]/', $senhanova); // Non-alpha/num characters (allows underscore)

if (password_verify($senhaatual, $Id_valor) && $senhanova == $senhaconfir && strlen($senhanova) >= '8' && strlen($senhaconfir) >= '8' && $ucl && $lcl && $Dig && $nos) {
    $stmt = 'UPDATE wp_inf.inf_users SET user_pass= ?, status= ? WHERE ID = ? '; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt = $stmt->execute([$senhafinal, $status, $id_util]);

}
```